# Using multiple predicate parameters on sjoin in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join, geodataframe, spatial-predicates

Looking for a way to run `GeoDataFrame.sjoin()` with more than one predicate.
For example, on QGIS' "Join by location" tool, there is a check box of predicates to mark as needed.

When trying to run predicates as a list :

```py
my_sjoin = gdf_1.sjoin(gdf_2, predicate=['within', 'intersects'])
```

The function wont accept a list:

> "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, intersects will also find the withins:

[Returns True if the boundary or interior of the object intersect in any way with those of the other.](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.intersects)

Which looks correct, **A** is completely within a grid cell:

```
import geopandas as gpd

df1 = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/grid.shp')
df2 = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/polygons.shp')

intersecting = sorted(list(set(df1.sjoin(df2, predicate='intersects')['polyid']))) #['A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L'] You might want a how='left' if you want to keep all features in df1
within = sorted(list(set(df2.sjoin(df1, predicate='within')['polyid']))) #['A', 'F', 'L'] #All are already above
```

[image]

Otherwise you would chain the joins, first one predicate/op, then the other